# How can I show/hide the rest of the table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with 500+ rows. I want to show only the first 3 rows by default and when a user clicks a button the rest of the rows would show up.

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>

<button>Show the rest of the rows</button>

  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please help. No jQuery, just JS.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried which didn't work.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events). This HTML is not valid. Please [validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: Please include all the code required to reproduce the problem. You can read the guidelines here on how to ask a questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Put the table in container with limited CSS `max-height` and `overflow: hidden`. And include button at the bottom of container toggling to something like `max-height: 300vh`. Unless you want to load the rest of the rows programmatically, hide it with CSS classes as you are loading it all already anyway.

Comment: How do I do that? How to toggle between **px and 100%?